# How to not use a singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton

According to [the article](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/), it is suggested to not use a singleton. However, what is the alternative or better way? For example, in my GUI, I have a log window. After an operation, no matter where it is, I can easily record some information in the log window if a singleton is used. The singleton provides a shortcut, although via a global route. If not using singleton, any good way to do it? Note the operations may scatter anywhere. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you instantiate whatever class manages the operation, pass it an `ILogger`.

Comment: It's entirely OK to have *global variables*. What's evil about the singleton that it works extra hard to prevent *multiple instantiations*. You can make your logger a global variable, and if you only need it once, just instantiate it once.

Comment: Or just keep it singleton. Really. I had a brief look at the article you cite and what I miss in that train of thoughts is the relationship to a factory. I wouldn't take these arguments very seriously.

Comment: There are two issues: 1) "I need one everywhere" and 2) "I only need one". Global variables handled number one, and that sounds like what you want. Number two is irrelevant; just don't make more than one. And if it's an error to have more than one, the constructor of your class will do that check *for itself* (and may even be *not* global).

Comment: Or you could always pull a rabbit out of the hat and do both. Have your log class support its writing using *class* variables, and everyone that makes a log *instance* eventually hits those. This was common when dealing with MTS objects (man I hated that product). So you have all these instances with no actual internal state, but they all share the class variables (like output file, handles, etc) and play cooperatively. No better performance than a singleton, but if you ever do decide to implement stand-along multi-instance support, your usage is already there (since everyone has an "object").

Comment: @WhozCraig I have seen that referred to as the "Borg pattern".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Never heard it called that, but how amazingly fitting. Thanks for that!.

Comment: The Borg idiom is also called [Monostate](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern). IMHO it is _very slightly_ better than Singleton because at least it's honest that it's just global state, instead of pretending that only allowing one instance to exist makes the code acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the simplest thing that could possibly work.  In my experience, the simplest way to do logging is to use free functions.

```
void logError(const std::string& message);
void logWarning(const std::string& message);
void logInfo(const std::string& message);
```

Maybe the implementation is just a global, maybe its not.  It doesn't matter how you implement it.  It only matters that they don't write different code based on how it is implemented.  Focus on the interface that is exposed.

IMHO, Singletons are bad because they are hard to change later.  Not because of the way they are implemented, but because they tend towards interfaces that only allow for there to be a singleton behind it.  That is hard to change.  When change is difficult, then it costs a lot to maintain.

Comment: "_Focus on the interface that is exposed._" +1, right. Maybe those functions use a Simpleton^W Singleton, maybe they don't, but the code using them shouldn't care.

Answer (score 2):

There are several common misunderstandings about Singleton.

The first is that it has any redeeming features and is useful. Wrong. It's crap.

The second misunderstanding is that it means "only have one object". **No**. It means "enforce the rule that there *can only be* one object." That's not the same thing.

The Singleton pattern in the Gang of Four *Design Patterns* book is a "Creational Pattern", because it's role is related to how an object is created.  The so-called pattern's purpose is to provide a single, global instance of an object *and prevent other instances being created*. e.g. make the constructor private and provide a single static function that is allowed to create *one* instance only. (The fact it has two responsibilities in one type should be a clue it is broken, it violates the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).)

If you must have a single global instance, then (although that might be a symptom of poor  design) you can do that quite simply by **just creating one**.  Then you don't need the "enforce the rule there can only be one" property, so you don't need the Singleton "pattern".

Too many people say "it's a Singleton" when they mean "there's only one of it", which is not the same as saying "I have used the language rules to guarantee *there can only be* one of it".

Or they say "I've got a Singleton" as though that justifies having a global variable. Giving it a fancy name does not excuse crap design.

If you need one instance, create one instance. Don't create more of them. Bingo, you have one instance. Easy. If you can't control how other bits of the program access that instance then your program is already broken. Fix the code. Stop relying on a single instance of the type. Preventing other instances being created doesn't solve your design problem, it just makes it worse.

This is the [Just Create One](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne) pattern.

If lots of code needs access to that object then pass it to the code (via constructors or function arguments) so the dependencies are explicit. This is the [Parameterize from Above](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1411) pattern.

For a logging module, the code that wants to log should not care that it's logging to a "Singleton" (i.e. a type that cannot have more than one instance,) it should either log to the logger it's passed, or it should log via a global function or object *which doesn't need to be a "Singleton"* it can just be a global that there is only one of.  Do you write code to enforce the rule there is only one `std::cout` and call `std::cout::instance()` or do you just accept it's a global and use it?  Do you call `printf::instance()("%s", ...)` or just `printf` and let the implementer of `printf` worry about how it works?